# Display an image in WinRT WebView control

Tags: c#, webview, windows-8, httpwebrequest, microsoft-metro

Say I have a `WebView` in my page, with its content loaded by `WebView.NavigateToString(string  html)`. Now the problem is the html string contains a few `<img>` tags like

```
<img src="http://www.remotefakesite.com/1.jpg" />
```

however the image can't be downloaded correctly unless the request has a special cookie. But the request is *sent* by the control, I don't know how to modify the request(adding a cookie to it). I've tried setting `HttpRequest.DefaultWebProxy`, but it doesn't work for the requests sent by the built-in control.

An alternative solution is downloading the image by my own HttpWebRequest(with the correct cookie) to local folder and then modify the img tag in the html string to

```
<img src="files:///xxxxx" />
```

but obviously `files:///` scheme is against the security policy of metro apps. Neither `ms-appx` nor `ms-appdata` works, because the downloaded images are not part of my project.

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image size isn't a problem, you could try to download it using a custom HTTP request with the required cookies, base64 encode it, and insert it into the src attribute:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR8Q..." />
```

And pass it with the rest of the html to the WebView using the NavigateToString method.

This might not be the *best* solution in the world, but it just works, compared to other options.

Answer (score 3):

I did some test here, and if you can download the image to example in the project folder.
Example in the "Media" folder, then you can open the image using this code:

```
<img src="ms-appx-web:///Media/10.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the Pictures Library capability of your app and use the picture library location for downloading the images. [Here is a guide on accessing pictures library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465191.aspx).

**Update:**

The image is then created from the image objects in the pictures library. An example would be:

```
async private void LoadImage()
{
    try
    {
        IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> resultsLibrary =
            await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
        MessageBlock.Text += "Show image: " + resultsLibrary[0].Name + "\n";
        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream imageStream =
            await resultsLibrary[0].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage imageBitmap =
            new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        imageBitmap.SetSource(imageStream);
        ImagePlayer.Source = imageBitmap;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBlock.Text += "Exception encountered: " + ex.Message + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what should I use in `<img src="here" />`?

Comment: What will `img.src` look like? What scheme is it using?

Comment: There is documentation for all these questions on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453196.aspx

Comment: This method is part of HTML5 but I'm using C#.

Comment: @DannyChen Oh I am changing the links to XAML from WinJS.

Comment: But I'm not loading images into a control. The image is embedded in a `WebView`, they are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use this, write just like HTML:

```
this.InitializeComponent();

string htmContent = @" <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.remotefakesite.com/1.jpg" />
</body>
</html>";

preview.NavigateToString(htmContent);
```

Only you need a webview element (here this called "preview")

Comment: I exactly did this. But the `<img>` won't be loaded correctly, because there is no cookie in the *get request*, so the image server won't return the image.

Comment: i test it and here i can see the image from my website. Have you enable the " Internet (Client & Server)"

Comment: The image in your website is a static image file, while it's not in my website.